# VMWARE ESXI 6.5

Tags: vmware, esxi

I have Dell R300 with VMWARE ESXI 6.5.
I use vSphere Client for administartion. I made the virtual machine mirror. It was easy.

Now i installed the secound VMWARE ESXI 6.5 on the secound R300 Dell server. 
I can not use the same vSphere Client for administration.
I've got the first warning about the certificate and the next few errors:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3ysswwe53734hg/2.jpg?dl=0

Any of options doesn't work:

1) run the installer: https://www.dropbox.com/s/00ffk7iujtqd8bg/3.jpg?dl=0

2) save the installer https://www.dropbox.com/s/it8ils1huaj8un5/4.jpg?dl=0

But, there is a web interface to manage the VMWARE. It was not avaliable on the first machine (https://www.dropbox.com/s/417e4cuxzjdsyi0/1.jpg?dl=0). But it is immpossible to upload the prevoius made mirror. There is a possibility to (only) upload to the storage separated files (one by one).

How can i restore the previous made mirror of Virtual Machine which was downloaded with vSphere Client (it contains about 8-10 files).

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the esxi hosts, you can use their web interface. just type their name/ip on your web browser (asuming you're on the same network)

In order to access both hosts with single web interface, you can install vcenter server as a virtual machine (it can be licensed with your vmware license or I guess you can by it from vmware): https://www.vmware.com/products/vcenter-server.html